# How can I install winINet.dll in visual studio c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, wininet

I tried to install *winiNet.dll* downloaded from [this](http://originaldll.com/file/wininet.dll/8649.html) site,

but when I tried to add it to the `C:\Windows\System32` directory i saw there already exists this file(*wininet.dll*). however, I tried to run the command `regsvr32 wininet.dll` in the command line but there was an error..

Anyway, Is there another way to add this *dll* to my project, then how?

Comment: thank you very much..now, I have another problem: I included winINet.h in my project but then the compiler made 292 errors. for examle: Error 1 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'HINTERNET' , Error 10 error C2378: 'INTERNET_PORT' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef . those errors appeared in WinInet.h file. what could I do to fix  it???

Comment: I included <Windows.h> but now the compiler made 63 same errors.for example: Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'constant'.     Error 17 error C2989: 'IRpcStubBuffer' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template.       I couldn't to solve it.. I would like if you help me.  thanks for the help..

Comment: please, it's urgent! I don't know how to solve this problem.....